# What's the difference between a recursive type and a list?

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm pretty new to OCaml (currently taking awful classes at uni) and we recently studied recursive types. We were told that we use that to create lists but there already are lists in OCaml so I don't really understand when I should be using one over the other.

example :

```ml
(* list made with a recursive type : *)
type int_list =
    | None
    | Element of int * int_list

(* just a list *)
let int_list2 : int list = []
```

Comment: You shouldn't, and there is no difference. It's just showing you how the built-in list is actually implemented.

Comment: `None` is already used by the option type. A better name I've seen in other examples would be `Nil`.

Comment: Not to mention there is no need to constrain this type to just working with `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the difference between a recursive type and a list?

"Recursive type" describes a whole category of types whereas `list` is one specific recursive type. In other words: `list` is a recursive type, but there are recursive types other than `list`.

> there already are lists in OCaml so I don't really understand when I should be using one over the other.

When you should use `int_list` over the built-in `list` type? Never. Your teacher showed you this definition as an example of what recursive types look like, not as something you should actually use.

You would define your own recursive types only when defining something that doesn't already exist in the standard library (except for learning exercises of course).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Sadly, we are expected to use recursive types all the time, even if the build in `list` type is far better in this context. Our professor openly said he didn't like match expressions and didn't see the point when we already have `if`. So yeah, that's why i made this post lol. Thanks again for explaining it!